# How activity C return to activity A in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Let say there are three activity

A->B->C

If I am returning from C to B , What I have to do is simply:

In C:

```
            onBackPressed();
```

And in B

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
.....
}

if (savedInstanceState != null) {
.....
}
```

The above code will handle the case for From C to B. However, what if C to A, what should I do? Also, how to handle if I would like all activities between A and C are destoryed when C to A? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also, how to handle if I would like all activities between A and C are destoryed when C to A?

Use this `Intent Flag`

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityC.this, ActivityA.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

> However, what if C to A, what should I do?

This flag will keep all `Activities` in between on the stack but bring A to the front

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityC.this, ActivityA.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(i);
```

In either case, you will want to call `finish()` on C after calling `startActivitiy()` if you want it removed.

You can find all `Intent Flags` [Here in the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: If you don't call `finish()` on A then it shouldn't be destroyed so you should be ok

Comment: Thanks for your help . Would you mind explain briefly how to track / log the activity stack? (I am using logcat) eg. what activity is queue in the stack now ? thanks

Comment: I found that when I use intent from A to B  , no matter I use the finish() or not , it will destory the activity A. Is it the default android behavior? (From one activity to another activity , the pervious activity is destoryed.)

Comment: I'm not sure how well I can explain it but basically the `Activities` are put on and taken off in the order they are created. So the `Activity` in the foreground is on the top of the stack. You should watch [This Google Video](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/ahNzfmdvb2dsZS1kZXZlbG9wZXJzcg4LEgVFdmVudBi56NsCDA) its very helpful in understanding the stack

Comment: If you aren't using any flags then it isn't destroying the `Activity` unless you call `finish()`, rather it is creating a new instance of the `Activity`